# Opening Google App Script - Forbidden 403 Error does not let me open

Tags: google-apps-script

i am the owner of the script and i am attempting to open script but I receive forbidden error 403.

please advise.

Comment: Please provide additional details of the actions you perform which result in the error.

Comment: Hello @friyay1224, are you still encountering the same issue after logging out and in again? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the same problem, trying to open the Script tabs on several Google Sheets.

Update: I logged out of the Google account, and then logged back in. This seems to have fixed the problem